# How to sort only certain columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, datatables

I am using [jQuery DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/) plugin to sort table data. I have four columns: Name, Position, Office and Age. What I want is user to be able to sort only Name and Age columns, not all the columns. But I am not able to stop sorting on OTHER columns. Can you please suggest something?

Comment: Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lovethakker/cv2tcm9d/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This code disable sorting, 0 - index of column.
For old version

```
aoColumnDefs: [
  {
     bSortable: false,
     aTargets: [ 0 ]
  }
]
```

for DataTables 1.10+

```
columnDefs: [
   { orderable: false, targets: 0 }
]
```

Especially for example, you need this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
        "aoColumns": [
           null,
           { "bSortable": false },
           { "bSortable": false },
           null
         ]
    } );
} );
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cv2tcm9d/1/)