# Using jQuery DataTable how to enable / disable column sorting by calling javascript function in C# application?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, datatable

I have created a table using jQuery DataTable in C# web application, and also I have created a SortBy dropdown and displaying all the column names in it.
Now, I am trying to enable/disable sorting functionality according to the selection of SortBy dropdown.

For ex: I have columns like: ID, Name, Gender, City, Country.

Now, when I select Country name in the SortBy dropdown, sorting will enable for Country column.

Please any one help me, I have google and checks many of the solutions but its not working.
Thanks.

Comment: datatables allows sorting of all columns by just clicking on the table header, why restrict it to certain columns selected by a drop down - seems like bad ux to me

Comment: Hi Pete, I understand that but it is the client requirement, client wants sorting functionality on the basis of the selected column in dropdown. Is any way to target the index of any column for sorting functionality.

Comment: I guess you would have to destroy and then re-intialise the datatable with the different column initialised - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31469921/how-to-sort-only-certain-columns or perhaps write your own sorting function: https://datatables.net/reference/api/sort(), but isn't it your job to tell the client that the amount of coding to add a feature that ruins ux will cost them more money and isn't worth it?

Comment: You are right, I also think so but, I was thinking is there will be any possibility to sort by targeting column index.
Thanks for your guidance Pete.